# Convert a plane string to date format in Python

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I have a plane text like '20211111012030' and need to convert it to '**YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS**'(2021-11-11 01:20:30) format in python .How can I convert it to a specific format as above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regex approach:

```py
inp = '20211111012030'
output = re.sub(r'(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})', r'\1-\2-\3 \4:\5:\5', inp)
print(output)  # 2021-11-11 01:20:20
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `datetime` package.

```
from datetime import datetime

dt_str = '20211111012030'
dt = datetime.strptime(dt_str, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
print(dt)
```